# How to import a WCF web service using a Java client

Tags: c#, wcf, java-client

I have a WCF web service using wsHttpBinding that I am consuming from a Java client. I generated code from the WSDL using wsimport.  The java client appears to be creating the service fine but when I call a method on the service the client just spins.

```
MyService s = new MyService();
IMyService i = s.getWSHttpBindingIMyService();
returnedValue = i.getSomething(2); // method call
```

Can a java client communicate with a WCF webservice that is using wsHttpBinding? And what is the best way of doing so?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll definitely want to use WSIT to help write your client, and it's probably easiest to use the whole [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/2.0/) stack.  Metro contains jaxws-ri, WSIT & JAB in its jars (webservices-rt.jar & webservices-api.jar).

A few steps to get you started:

1. Does the published WSDL of the WCF service contain a WS-Policy section?  If not, get that info & place it into your local local copy of the the service WSDL file.   Re-run wsimport on the WSDL containing the WS-Policy section.
2. Include the metro jars on your client's classpath.
3. Write a file named wsit-client.xml file & place it into WEB-INF/classes (or on your classpath).  Here's a [sample](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-1072/6ncp48v6d?a=view).   Now, when you use the client, you should see an INFO message in your console that says:  WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration from file:
4. If you get stuck on WS-Policy or wsit-client.xml, use Netbeans.  I use Eclipse for development, and while I don't really like Netbeans, I've used it as a reference a number of times, because it has configuration settings in the IDE that will enable you to secure web services & write a web service client that needs security, and it'll generate wsit-client.xml & WSDLs with WS-Policy info in them for you.  Try writing a web application in Netbeans & pointing to the service's WSDL to generate a web service client there & see what the resulting files look like.
5. You can get some questions answered here on SO, but the java.net Metro [forum](http://forums.java.net/jive/forum.jspa?forumID=46&start=0) is also pretty active, and you can get good support there as well.  Just be prepared for answers like "do XYZ in Netbeans/Glassfish".

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would help: [WCF service & Java client](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/623b3d07-c1c9-4ff1-8bb4-36a2fd234b90/)